# Add conditional color to Treemap

Tags: highcharts

Trying to add color to Heatmap.  The color is based on the values with the following conditions.

```
if value 'equals or less than': -3.0 (green)
if value less than or equal to' -1.0 (red)
if value equals zero (grey)
if value 'greater than or equal to' 0.1 (orange)
if value 'greater than or equal to' 3.0 (purple)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d_paul/rq862nuv/

Comment: But your demo is a Treemap, not Heatmap? Anyway, you need to use [`colorAxis.dataClasses`](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/colorAxis.dataClasses) to define these steps. Btw, what should happen when value is for example 0.01? Or -0.4? Here is a simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/rq862nuv/2/

Comment: 0.01 will be rounded to zero.

Comment: Ok, just don't forget to round data **before** rendering a chart.

Comment: Because other values are negative or zero. These values should be always positive to properly calculate the tree.

Comment: You can create an idea on the [UserVoice](https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api). As for the workaround, I would use always positive values, and use tooltip formatter to display the real value.

Comment: I understand, still use my workaround, for example: https://jsfiddle.net/rq862nuv/6/ Note: zeros will not be rendered anyway.. (zero takes zero space in the tree).

Comment: For zeros: see my comment above: `Note: zeros will not be rendered anyway.. (zero takes zero space in the tree).`. I mean box in a tree map for value=0 is rendered as 0x0 px block, so you won't see it (actually it's not rendered at all, as 0x0 px blocks don't make sense). Regarding only two colors: see `getColor()` method which generates colors. Simply add more if-else statements there.

Comment: Then maybe change the value from 0 to some small value, for example 0.1 ? Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/rq862nuv/7/

Comment: In your code you have `Math.round()` so all values in range (-0.5, 0.5) are rendered as 0. Maybe `parseFloat()` is a better solution?Maybe you could tell me the size of 0 boxes? Those are rendered with the same size as any other point? I'm really curious about it :) Maybe they use different algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you defined as point's value, in fact it should be the point's `colorValue`. `value` is the information about the point's size, `colorValue` about its color. colorValue might be a negative number - value must not. If you want the point's size depends on its color, you need to transform colorValue scale to some positive scale, e.g. `[1, 10]`.

If you define colorValue for points, then you can use `colorAxis.dataClasses` and the colors will be applied.

```
var dataMin = points.filter(p => !isNaN(p.value)).reduce((min, p) => Math.min(min, p.value), Infinity);
var dataMax = points.filter(p => !isNaN(p.value)).reduce((max, p) => Math.max(max, p.value), -Infinity);

var newMin = 1;
var newMax = 10;

function transformValue (value) {
  return (newMax - newMin) * (value - dataMin) / (dataMax - dataMin) + newMin;
}

var transformedData = points.map(p => {
  var transformedPoint = Object.assign({}, p);

  if (p.value !== undefined) {
    transformedPoint.value = transformValue(p.value);
    transformedPoint.colorValue = p.value;
  }

  return transformedPoint;
});
```

Classes for colorAxis

```
  colorAxis: {
dataClasses: [{
  to: -3,
  color: '#00ff00'
}, {
  from: -3,
  to: -1,
  color: '#ff0000'
}, {
  from: 0,
  to: 0,
  color: '#000000'
}, {
  from: 0.1,
  to: 3,
  color: '#0000ff'
}, {
  from: 3,
  color: '#00ffff'
}]
},
```

example with the transformed data: https://jsfiddle.net/aepu6dvt/

example with the points with the same size: https://jsfiddle.net/aepu6dvt/1/

Comment: Can you make the size of a box proportional relative to its value e.g. box with a value 0.20 will be smaller than a box with value 0.30 etc, like you see in the [second image](http://picpaste.com/Screen_Shot_2017-04-26_at_18.01.06-zgouPCl7.png)

Comment: They are proportional - if you investigate in dev tools their pixel size, they will be different. The major factor in building box size and position is layoutAlgorithm - if you are not satisfied with the size discrepancies, you can create your own algorithm - see Algorithms section here https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/treemap

Comment: whats the difference between the 'transformed data' and 'same size' examples? Noticed the first example does not show 'South-East Asia'

Comment: 'same size' has boxes with the same size = width * length, in transformed data size = width * length has different value according to the point's value.

Comment: 1)Can't see 'South-East Asia' in the tranformed data version (first one). 2)Notice how the left hand side of the [second image](http://picpaste.com/Screen_Shot_2017-04-26_at_18.01.06-zgouPCl7.png) as the boxes get smaller the labels disappear. Is this behaviour default with the 'slice and dice' algorithm?

Comment: It's a mistake in your data in your example - weirdly, I did not changed it in my first example - see the data['South-East Asia']['Bangladesh']['Type D'] - it cannot be parsed to a number. I do not think you can achieve the same layout as in the image with the default algorithms. You can investigate the details in the source code http://code.highcharts.com/modules/treemap.src.js - the general algorithm is in algorithmFill function